# Reconstruct a lost shopping cart

Tags: database, magento-1, shopping-cart

A user added items to her cart last night. Somehow her session was lost and this morning when she tried to check out, they were gone. She had spent several hours shopping and is quite frustrated. We have to find her cart items or lose the sale.

There is an "abandoned carts" area of the admin, but it seems to only reflect logged in users, so it is useless for me.

I am looking at the database table `report_event`. Looking at entries from last night, and limiting by `event_type_id` = 4 (which is `event_name` = "checkout_cart_add_product" in table `report_event_types`), I see two groups of entries from around the time she was shopping. Each group has the same `subject_id`, which I'm thinking might connect to a user session. The object ids are all different but I don't know what they are. Are they product_ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik magento doesn't clean up, so if she was not logged in, you should find her quote in the `sales_flat_quote` table and all the items in `sales_flat_quote_item` table. You can try to but her `customer_id` on the quote, check that there is no other and activcate it.

Not sure wether this works, though.

Comment: I was able to find exactly the items she lost with your help. In `sales_flat_quote` I found a cart with 10 items in it. Then searching for that line's id as the `entity_id` in `sales_flat_quote_item` I found the list of items. I did not try to restore the cart, since that seems too hard. But I did email her the list of items, for which she was grateful.